# Unable to change the settings in meld when I launch it with sudo

Tags: sudo, root, su, d-bus, dconf

When I launch meld with `sudo`, `su`, `gksu` or `gksudo` I have the following output:

```
(meld:1666): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(meld:1666): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_proxy_get_name_owner: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed

(meld:1666): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=745b249ad9024475816761582a9ee2ca --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```

And I am not able to change the settings.
In comparison, I use geany with sudo without any problem, error or warning, and I am able to change the geany's settings.

I use:

- meld 3.16.4
- dconf 0.26.0
- glib2 2.50.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this topic: [dbus not accessible via kdesu/sudo, but recompiling dbus helps](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224266), I have to recompile `dbus`.
So this is what I did on my Archlinux system

```
# installs arch build system
sudo pacman -S abs

# download the abs dbus (do it with the root user)
abs core/dbus

# copy the files in my HOME
cp -r /var/abs/core/dbus/ ~/abs

# compile dbus
cd ~/abs/dbus
makepkg -s

# install the compiled package
sudo pacman -U dbus-1.10.16-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

And that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Installing dbus-x11 worked for me.

```
apt install dbus-x11
```

I can now change preferences and see no errors in cli at start-up.